# How to integrate Hyperledger Fabric Network and Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am learning Hyperledger Fabric for Enterprise Blockchain. I have setup a network of an organization with orderer, ca, peer and cli running as docker containers(I will be setting up other organizations on other computers instead of dockerzing the whole process).

1.I want to know how I can use hyperledger composer in the scene. I 
  would like to code and deploy chaincode on the channel I have setup, 
  but I am clueless how to do so using composer.

2.The documentation of Composer has steps which involve setting up and 
  run their blockchain docker files.

My efforts :

Went through composer documentation but to no avail. I have traversed createPeerAdminCard.sh and modified it to generate card using peer channel-artifacts of my blockchain network. But on importing it to composer via cli or composer-playground, I see None under the Business Network section of the card on browser interface of fabric-composer.

Please help as I am stuck on this problem for quite long.
[image of composer-playground output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKZjR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the image, it seems you have not deployed any BNA yet.

Follow this [link](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) to setup hyperledger fabric. Once everything is up and running then you can deploy sample BNA in playgound(already loaded in composer UI).

You can use composer playgound itself to create your own BNA. Sample composer setup is available [here](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/editor)

Comment: Thanks @Gaurang Singh. I will go through the links and will implement the same. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger composer is no longer in active development. It is best to implement the chaincode yourself

Comment: Thanks. I am studying HL from book Hands-On Blockchain with Hyperledger by Packt.
The book uses GO to develop chaincodes but not from scratch and ideologically but to demonstrate their own network idea. I would like a more atomic view of the stuff and that too in NodeJS. If you can help me with informative guide, it would be a great help.

Comment: Ah thats great, I too am looking to switch from Go to NodeJS at the moment- this is what I am following https://fabric-shim.github.io/master/tutorial-using-chaincodeinterface.html

Comment: With node, I have run into a new issue, I have three organizations having 1 endorser peer each and only 1 orderer across three orgs. I have implemented a chaincode and instantiated it via cli. Now I have this function which calls for stub.putState and try creating a new key value. But it always end up getting marked as invalid transaction. Exact err: VSCCValidateTx for transaction {txn_id} returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy.

for an 'OR' policy, things work fine, but for AND, it doesn't.